# How to implement effective queries with query time boosting in Lucene

Tags: search, lucene, search-engine

I try to implement a query which have the boosting. I wanna ask with an example:

**Fields:** views(LongField), timeMillis(LongField), content(TextField), type(StringField), userId(StringField)

I wanna search a word in content field. But I must boost with views, timeMillis and type fields.

**The indexed Documents are here:**

1. *timeMilles:* 1465558045071 *views:* 32 *userId:* 1 *type:* client *content:* testing Testing
2. *timeMilles:* 1465551034310 *views:* 18 *userId:* 2 *type:* client *content:* testing Testing
3. *timeMilles:* 1465558048204 *views:* 2 *userId:* 1 *type*: admin *content*: testing Testing
4. *timeMilles:* 1465551037318 *views:* 28 *userId:* 2 *type:* client *content:* testing Testing
5. *timeMilles:* 1465551039323 *views:* 22 *userId:* 3 *type:* admin *content:* testing Testing

**The order of importance in the fields for query time boosting:** type, timeMilles, views

**The expected result like:**

1. *timeMilles:* 1465551039323 *views:* 22 *userId:* 3 *type:* admin *content:* testing Testing
2. *timeMilles:* 1465558048204 *views:* 2 *userId:* 1 *type:* admin *content:* testing Testing
3. *timeMilles:* 1465558045071 *views:* 32 *userId:* 1 *type:* client* content:* testing Testing
4. *timeMilles:* 1465551037318 *views:* 28 *userId:* 2 *type:* client content: testing Testing
5. *timeMilles:* 1465551034310 *views:* 18 *userId:* 2 *type:* client *content:* testing Testing

I think grouping views and timeMilles with certain intervals and creating queries for these intervals. After that, I set boost value for these interval queries as their importance. For example, 0.1f for 1<=views<=10, 0.2f for 11<=views<=20, etc. It can be thougt same for the timeMilles field.

Secondly, I think creating a term queries which have a term text for type field. The text for terms are "admin" and "client". The boost value of "admin" query is bigger than "client" query.

Finally, I create content query and then I add all queries to a boolean query. When I search like these queries. My result is similar to the expected result but it is not correct.

1. *timeMilles:* 1465558048204 *views:* 2 *userId:* 1 *type:* admin *content:* testing Testing
2. *timeMilles:* 1465551039323 *views:* 22 *userId:* 3 *type:* admin *content:* testing Testing
3. *timeMilles:* 1465558045071 *views:* 32 *userId:* 1 *type:* client* content:* testing Testing
4. *timeMilles:* 1465551034310 *views:* 18 *userId:* 2 *type:* client *content:* testing Testing
5. *timeMilles:* 1465551037318 *views:* 28 *userId:* 2 *type:* client content: testing Testing

How can I correct the result like the expected result? Can you give me any advices for boosting strategy on one more fields?

Comment: Why are you *describing* your code instead of just posting the code?  That said, I think you should probably use [Sort](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html), rather than relying on boosts to order your results.

Comment: Hi @femtoRgon , I don't need to post the code because I think I described the the code clearly. Also, I am newbie on Lucene and I wanna get advice for Sorting and Boosting in such that case. I try to use Sort one more SortFields and then It works more worse than Boostings.